# Django orderby in CBV

Tags: python, django

I want to order my queryset, by `nev`, but its not working? What am I doing wrong? My Cbv:

```
class MunkakorListView(ListView):

model = Munkakor

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MunkakorListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    template_name = 'MunkakorKarbantart/MunkakorokList.html'
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = self.model.objects.all()
    qs=qs.order_by('nev')
    search = self.request.GET.get('search_box', None)
    orderby = self.request.GET.get('orderby', None)
    if search:
        qs=qs.filter(nev__icontains=search)


    return qs
```

Model:

```
class Dolgozo(models.Model):
    dolgozo_id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    nev = models.CharField('Név',max_length=30)
```

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? invalid results? Please use the description section to *describe* your question

Comment: Its just literally does nothing, not errors at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the orderby parameter from the GET, but you're not doing anything with it. You need to use it to actually order the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like to order my queryset, by 'nev'

for ascending:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = self.model.objects.order_by('nev')
```

for descending:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.order_by('-nev')
```

Comment: may be he wants desc as you said  not mention any error/log very hard for us to detect what happen